# Interrupt a function in Qt c++ when it has a timer

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qtimer

I'm trying to make a program in Qt. I will not send all, but the fragment with which I have a problem. The point is, I have to interrupt a function that has a Timer in it, but I don't know how to interrupt it while it's waiting before timer.  Please reply!

```
void MainWindow::Test(){
    TestWrite();       //TestWrite is a function where I write my answer 
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, this, &MainWindow::TestCheck);     //TestCheck is a function where the answer is checked 
}
 
void MainWindow::on_Test_clicked()
{
    Test();
    timer = new QTimer(this);           //Creates a timer and calls the Test function every 7 seconds 

    timer->connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::Test);
    timer->start(7000);
}
 
........
........
 
void MainWindow::on_Back_clicked()
{
    timer->stop();   //I am trying to make the "Back" button interrupt the Test, TestWrite and TestCheck functions. Now, if you quickly click "Back" and "Test", the effect is as if you did not click the "Back" button 
}
```

Comment: The way you stated your question shows a possible mis-understanding of how timers work in Qt. Nothing is "waiting" for a timer, but rather an expired timer sends a signal to a slot. "Waiting" in Qt would freeze your user interface.

Comment: Are you aware that you are actually starting two timers in your code? A periodic and a single-shot one?

Answer (score 2):

Timers in Qt that you start with the static `QTimer` functions (like you do in `MainWindow::Test`) cannot be stopped at all, because there's no timer object exposed to you that you could use to `stop()` (or otherwise manipulate) the timer. Such timers will expire in any case, and they will emit their signal in any case. You need to decide in your *slot* whether you're still interested in the signal.

When you create an explicit timer object (as you do in `on_test_clicked()`, you can only `stop()` it, or re-`start()` it with a minimum expiry time (0) to have it expire "immediately".

If you don't want to have a timer expire that you already started, simply `stop()` it.

The way you stated your question shows a possible mis-understanding of how timers work in Qt. Nothing is "waiting" for a timer, but rather an expired timer sends a signal to a slot. "Waiting" in Qt would freeze your user interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I would just like to implement an algorithm in Qt which, after clicking "Back", would break the "Test" function and all functions called by Timer. Do you know where I can read about how to implement it? Or something general about programming styles in Qt taking into account the time gap?

Comment: You still have your logic backwards. There's no "waiting". If you don't want a running timer to expire (which results in sending the signal), simply `stop()` the timer in response to pressing your button and the signal will not be sent (Don't forget to clean up by deleting the timer, as it stands, you seem have a memory leak). Re-work the other single shot timer started in `Test` so that you can `stop()` it as well.